# How to handle multiple social accounts with different emails?

Tags: authentication, social-networking, facebook-login, google-signin

I have an application that allows users to sign up with google and facebook. Both provides email information when sign in.
My problem is that facebook account is associated with an different email than google, so its creating two accounts to the "same" user.
How to solve this problem?

I was thinking about this flow:

1. User sign up with email and password
2. In user profile user can associate its account with facebook, google, etc..
3. From now on user can sign in with facebook, google, etc...

Is this the best way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a good way to solve the problem.

You can also let him authorize with Google+ and Facebook before registration, check if the user is in the database already with that account (Facebook or Google+ ID), and if he is NOT in the database you redirect him to the registration form.